# How can the 10 Sephirot be understood in practice?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, practical-kabbalah, sefirot-attributes

I more or less understand the theory behind the 10 Sephirot, but what are practical examples that could help me deepen my understanding?

**UPDATE**

I refer to these [10 Sephirot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephirot)

For example, Chesed represents kindness and love. How do I find this information useful?

Comment: practical examples of what?

Comment: Perhaps if you summarize the theory you understand, people can provide you with examples thereof. You tagged this [tag:mysticism-kabbalah] and [tag:practical-kabbalah], but did you mean perhaps [tag:mussar-ethics] instead?

Comment: are you looking for practical examples of kindness and love? Hug a lost puppy maybe?

Comment: @Danno is that allowed? it seems like hibuk (hugging) of an ereva

Comment: Sefer Tomer Devorah by Rav Moshe Cordevero is a GREAT resource for using the middot of Hashem practically

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114233/sfirot-vesrus-midot/114284#114284 related

Comment: Learn Etz chayim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Kabbalah 101 Series from Aish HaTorah: http://www.aish.com/sp/k/

It goes through each sephira as a concept, as a foundation, and then explores other concepts.

It has many practical examples, e.g.—

> "Thus the act of burying a dead person is called chesed shel emes –-
>   "true kindness." For any act of chesed that is accorded to a person
>   during his life is never "pure," it carries within itself some of the
>   complexities of human interaction. Maybe I owe him a favor and am
>   uncomfortable in refusing him, or perhaps I like having him owe me
>   one. While with regard to other mitzvot this would be a mere "blemish"
>   on an otherwise fine deed, with regard to chesed, this corrupts its
>   very essence. For chesed by definition is "something for nothing."

A rabbi will be the best source for learning more.

Answer (score 1):

i am still trying to figure this out, for now it seems to me that they are subconscious parts of you soul that come out (reveal themselves) into your consciousness (thought, speech and action over which you have direct control at anytime (thought you can not stop but can make yourself think of other things))

i understand that you can effect them to but you can not be sure they are completely effected

above them (affecting/causing them to be a certain way) is pleasure/will (keser)
if you count keser you do not count daas (you always have 10 (something like the zohar numbers them 10))

i am not counting daas

i see them practically like this

the 3 heads

1 chochmo: (almost impossible to see an effect, but) i think i feel (it comes to my consciousness from it) it when i understand something that i thought was impossible to understand becomes possible to understand (i saw even a non jewish source that to have a new idea their needs to be a distraction or a giving up for a moment and then it comes to you)

2 bina: when you rely on you subconscious to make connections with previous information you already understood (not what you are thinking about now but other things you know) and what comes, comes from bina

3 daad: when it comes into consciousness it is a felling that the theory is real (fact) not just imagination but part of this world (a shote has problems with his daas, the way he feels what is face/real part of this world)

the lower 7, for now the only way i see them clearly (it comes to my consciousness from them) is when i am not to heavy headed but relaxed (light headed) (probably because if i am not light headed the midos that come to me are a mix for example chesed she'be'gvura)

1 chesed: when i am light headed and giving/doing-for people of what they ask me (they ask me and i just do it for them (doing is conscious))

2 gevura: the opposite of chesed i do not do what they ask of me unless i know i owe them

3 tiferes: i know i should not give/do-for them but i do it anyway

4 netsach: when i am walking down a narrow the street and someone (not someone you are obligated to respect or disrespect) is walking in the opposite direction (and i need to decide what to do) and i light headedy continue walking straight (probably it is also the urge to win)

5 hoid: is the same story but i let go more to the side to let the other person go beside me (probably it is also the urge to thank/admit)

6 yesoid: is the same story but i stop in my place and let the other person decide how to avoid me (probably it is also the urge not to buge from your principles)

7 malchus: not yet clear to me, but probably if is the urge to rule

it is still a work in progress for me to really understand them (the subconscious, that they are real cause of my actions), and by doing that to understand more about G-d almighty